# Jenkins cannot read json file

Tags: docker, jenkins, postman

I am trying to use postman/newman to auto test my API collection on Jenkins(build on docker),

I have successfully used the following shell (the url is the sample on postman Official website)

```
newman run "https://www.postman.com/collections/8a0c9bc08f062d12dcda"
```

but while I change the url to my own collection(I put in my git project),

url : newman run "http://localhost:8080/job/projectName/ws/pm/collection.json"

the eror messqge shows that

```
+ newman run http://localhost:8080/job/projectName/ws/pm/collection.json
error: collection could not be loaded
  the url "http://localhost:8080/job/xxx/ws/pm/collection.json" did not provide valid JSON data
  Unexpected token '<' at 1:1
<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2Fjob%2Fmone
^

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I also tried

url : newman run "localhost:8080/job/projectName/ws/pm/collection.json"

and the error code become

```
error: collection could not be loaded
  unable to read data from file "localhost:8080/job/projectName/ws/pm/collection.json"
  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'localhost:8080/job/projectName/ws/pm/collection.json'
```

Anyone can help? Please!!!

Comment: please chck you collection json whether you have any html code or not.
if not then please check by using curl http://localhost:8080/job/projectName/ws/pm/collection.json

Comment: I  put into my project directly after I export from postman.So I think it should't have any html code,

Comment: localhost:8080/job/projectName/ws/pm/collection.json, the error code changes as I edit

Answer (score 0):

I just fix the path and it works!
The path should be pm/collection.json
http://localhost:8080/job/xxx/ws/pm/collection.json is from workspace